# Garbage value at the beginning of decrypted text (AES 128 bit) when encrypting from angular 8

Tags: java, angular, encryption, aes, cryptojs

My backend AES-128 decryption logic is correct as when i do AES-128 encryption in java then it decrypts it properly. Now i tried to replicate the encryption logic in Angular 8, and then the decrypted text now contains garbage value at the initial bytes and remaing half string is correct (something like this ��da%:���mL���͔1","add":"uk","com":"wow"}).

Below is my angular code for encryption

```
encryptData(value: any) {
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(this.generateIV());
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef');
    var aesEncrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(value.toString()), key,{
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
      });

    console.log(JSON.stringify({
                        payloadToken: this.getRSAEncryption("0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"), 
                        payloadVariable: aesEncrypted.iv.toString() , 
                        payloadText: aesEncrypted.toString()}
                ));
    return aesEncrypted.toString();

  }

generateIV() {
    var key = "";
    var hex = "0123456789abcdef";

    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      key += hex.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 15));
    }
    return key;
  }
```

and below is my decryption logic in java

```
public static String packetDecryption(String requestPacket){
      DecryptedTokenPacket decryptedTokenPacket = GSON.fromJson(requestPacket, 
      DecryptedTokenPacket.class);
      SecretKey key2 = new SecretKeySpec(decryptedTokenPacket.getDecData(), 0, 
      decryptedTokenPacket.getDecData().length, EncConstants.ENC_ALGO);
      // Instantiate the cipher
     Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(EncConstants.CBC_ALGO);
     byte[] ivBytes = new Base64().decode(decryptedTokenPacket.getPayloadVariable());
     cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key2, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
     byte[] encryptedTextBytes = new Base64().decode(decryptedTokenPacket.getPayloadText());
     byte[] decryptedTextBytes;
     decryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);
     return new String(decryptedTextBytes);
}

//this function is used in the gateway for decrypting the secret key and then pass through
public DecryptedTokenPacket decryptKeyUsingRSA(EncryptedPacket encryptedPacket){
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA_ALGO);
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
                byte[] decData = cipher.doFinal(new Base64().decode(encryptedPacket.getPayloadToken()));
                decryptedTokenPacket.setPayloadText(encryptedPacket.getPayloadText());
                decryptedTokenPacket.setPayloadVariable(encryptedPacket.getPayloadVariable());
                decryptedTokenPacket.setDecData(decData);
return decryptedTokenPacket;
}
```

Beans

```
public class DecryptedTokenPacket {
    private String payloadVariable;
    private String payloadText;
    private byte[] decData;
}

public class EncryptedPacket {
    private String payloadVariable;
    private String payloadText;
    private String payloadToken;
}
```

Not sure what is causing this garbage value at the beginning. Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Your Java decryption code expects the payload variable and payload text to both be base64. In your Angular code I don't see anything performing base64 encoding. Instead you're just calling `toString()`. Are you expecting that to perform base64-encoding, and is it documented to do that?

Comment: I also note that you're generating a 15 character IV, each character of which can never be f. I'd expect both occurrences of 15 to be 16 in your generateIV function. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the suggestions, I tried removing the toString() function but the result was same. also when i replace all the occurences of 15 to 16 in generateIV function. i get the below exception "java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long". Now i remember this was the reason i made it 15

Comment: I've only just noticed that you're trying to treat the output of generateIV as base64, but you're generating hex. That's very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);

Comment: we want the iv to be in base64 encoding. WordArray is a different format